# How can I place a double-wide figure float (ie, figure*) on the bottom on the first page of a two-column document

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, starred-version

In what I would like to be a two-page, two-column document with two wide (`figure*`) figures, I need one to be on the bottom of the first page, and one to be on the top or bottom of the second.

However, LaTeX can't place wide figures on the bottom by default at all apparently without the use of an extra package (either `stfloats` or `dblfloatfix`), and both of these packages can only place a float on the page *after* its location in the source, making it impossible to have a double float on the first page.

Is there any way to get around this limitation, and have a float on the bottom of the first page?

It's worth noting that the simple idea of putting the float before the real first page doesn't work.

Comment: werner's answer is good.  but here's another approach: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107270/579)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mention that very specific requirements for the document - only two pages, and a two-column format. The following minimal example duplicates this using the [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol). It allows multiple column document format via the `multicols` environment that takes a mandatory argument:

```
\begin{multicols}{<n>}
  ...
\end{multicols}
```

This is an option in lieu of specifying a `twocolumn` document class option. As such, specifying your first image before starting the `multicols` environment, and specifying the second image after produces the desired result. The first image is still specified within a `figure` float with a float specifier of `[b]` (for `b`ottom placement) while the last figure has a float specifier of `[t]` (for `t`op placement):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{figure1}
  \caption{This is the first figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{multicols}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{figure2}
  \caption{This is the second figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is loaded with the `demo` package option which replaces all images with a 150pt x 100pt black rectangle (for compatibility reason). You should remove this for your document. Also, [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to generate dummy text.

Comment: What if one needs to have (one column-wide) figures inside the two-column environment? As far as I understand, `multicol` doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, because the figure command is placed before the multicol command, it is possible for the figure to float at the bottom of the first page. My document was still struggling with your script, until I changed `\begin{figure}[b]` into `\begin{figure}[b!]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.