# Figure* on first page in IEEEtran template

Tags: ieeetran, multicolumn

Is it possible to place a figure* (two column figure) on the bottom of the first page of a document? I'm writing an IEEEtran journal.

A figure* is always placed on the next page, so it is not possible to get it on the first page this way. Is there any workaround?

I tried it this way:

```
\documentclass[journal]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\author{author}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[b]
\centering
\dashbox{5}(400,100){\huge figure}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to help us help you, could you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: If this is going to be an official submission to IEEE you can't have a two column figure on the first page according to their specifications.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started.  It is based on Werner's previous solution [How can I place a double-wide figure float (ie, figure*) on the bottom on the first page of a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33803/how-can-i-place-a-double-wide-figure-float-ie-figure-on-the-bottom-on-the-fi).

However, using the single column document class option changes some of the other formatting. For example the abstract environment looks different in single column mode.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{author}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[b]
\centering
\dashbox{5}(400,100){\huge figure}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This indeed works, but i'm required to use the journal document class. This unfortunately doesn't seem to work in a journal. Do you know of a method to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: @user91273  If it is the journal that requires this, why don't you ask the journal of they allow this and if so how? It is often a waste of time attempting to do redefine stuff that the journal will just remove later on because it contradicts journal policy.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify IEEEtran.cls in order to achieve this?