# two column float with same page using multicols

Tags: floats, multicol

I have using `multicol` package and not able to fit the `figure` float in the same Page. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics,lipsum,multicol}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\begin{figure*}[b]\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\textwidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\end{figure*}\medskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{Figure}
\centering
{\includegraphics{16627ans_171}}
\end{Figure}
and...

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I'm expecting the output as per below:

[image]

Comment: Drop the float then;-)

Comment: @Christian: I had added `float` package and still not got the output. Any ideas?

Comment: I wrote: 'Drop' the float nature of the figure, not `\usepackage{float}` ;-)

Comment: two possibilities: [How can I place a double-wide figure float (ie, figure*) on the bottom on the first page of a two-column document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33803/579) and [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107270/579)

Comment: Could you give some feedback, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
%\makeatletter
%\newenvironment{Figure}
%  {\begin{figure*}[b]\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\textwidth}}
%  {\endminipage\par\end{figure*}\medskip}
%\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{multicols}%

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{16627ans_171}
%\captionof{figure}{Some Caption} % if needed
\end{center}
and... \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using `multicols` you can't add a float the same page. Simply will not happen.

However, there is a slight workaround on the page you start the `multicols`. Add the float *before* starting the `multicols`. To whit:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics,lipsum,multicol}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\begin{figure*}[b]\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\textwidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\end{figure*}\medskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\begin{Figure}
\centering
{\includegraphics{16627ans_171}}
\end{Figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-1]
and...

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Will put the float at the bottom of the current page, because it was created outside the `multicols`. It is not a general-case solution, but it does work in this (rather narrow) case.