# Placing figures at the bottom of two-column articles

Tags: floats, two-column

I've read numerous posts about placing figures at the bottom of two-column articles, and worked out that using `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` is the way to go. However, I can't work out how to do it so the figure shows at the first page of the article.

It brings the figure to the bottom of the page, but at the the bottom of the **second page**, not the **first page**. I've tried combining the *!b* with *h*, but nothing changed.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % For fill text
\usepackage{graphicx} % For example picture

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    % Header first page
    \noindent\LARGE{\textbf{Article title which doesn't split in two columns}}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse} \vspace{1cm}

  ]


\section{Section A}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure*}[!b]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

\section{Section B}
\lipsum[5-8]

\section{Section C}
\lipsum[9-14]

\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [How can I place a double-wide figure float (ie, figure*) on the bottom on the first page of a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33803/134144)  and [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107270/134144)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however there was an easier approach (see answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In normal circumstance is not allowed to have figures over two column on the bottom of the first page (due to information about article, which are usually as footnote at bottom of the first column). If you still like to have figure there, you can help yourself by using of the `stfloats` package:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % For fill text
\usepackage{graphicx} % For example picture

\usepackage{stfloats} % <---

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
    % \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    % Header first page
    % \noindent
    \LARGE\textbf{Article title which doesn't split in two columns}
    % \end{@twocolumnfalse} 
    \vspace{1cm}
          ]

\section{Section A}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[!b]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[2-4]

\section{Section B}
\lipsum[5-8]

\section{Section C}
\lipsum[9-14]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, it worked like a charm! Thank you, you saved my day :)

Comment: Is the @twocolumnfalse really needed, since the optional argument of \twocolumn is always one column?

Comment: not here (nor the `\noindent` or the brace group around `\textbf`) but it is needed if for example you use `\maketitle` in there so it knows to use a full width layout.