# page wide figure on page 1 in two column document

Tags: floats, two-column

i know its been a highly discussed topic already but i did not find a clever and universal solution for my problem yet. I am writing my master thesis right now and i would like to have a pagewide figure on my first page (not titlepage) on the bottom.
Unfortunately it seems like that figure* does not support "first page" placed images. It jumps always on the second page. Does anyone knows a way around this problem?

my enviroment looks like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 11pt, a4paper]{article}
... packages...
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
\section{Introduction}
text
\begin{figure*}[!hb]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=14.5cm]{Figure.png}
\end{figure*}
```

Thank you very much for your help and advices.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A figure is almost always placed on the next page, because at the time LaTeX sees it, it is too late to re-arrange the boxes of the current page. Therefore, if you want to place a figure on a certain page, you need to put it somewhere earlier in the code.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I tried to do that. But due to the fact, that the page before that is the title page, it does not work. i also tried to instert it before my section title. but it jumps on the second page too

Comment: Possible duplicate: [LaTeX figures in two column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66467/5764)

Comment: Probably even more similar: [Placing figures at the bottom of two-column articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522895/47927)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (with [`stfloats`](//ctan.org/pkg/stfloats)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,stfloats}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  This is a title page.
\end{titlepage}

\begin{figure*}[!hb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=14.5cm]{example-image}
\end{figure*}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner! you were right, i missed the articles you liked. the package "stfloats" made it possible!